# При сдвиге элемента в правую сторону появляется прокрутка. Как решить эту проблему

Tags: html, css

При сдвигании абсолютного элемента с отрицательным значением в правую сторону появляется прокрутка. Раньше с таким не сталкивался, всё работало нормально.

Пример:

```css
.block {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Блок</div>
```

Нужно что бы прокрутка не появлялась, а блок уходил на половину на право.

***Не использовать scrollbar display none***

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.continer{
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100vh;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="continer"><div class="block">Блок</div></div>
```

Comment: Можете объяснить почему нужно задавать overflow родительскому элементу? Оно же должно было работать и без этого. Это что обновление браузеров что ли?

Comment: У меня меню работает и без overflow

Comment: если зададите пустой html файл и просмотрите у body, main - тэгов дэфолтные стили браузера то ovefflow там будет со значением auto , тобишь если контент будет уходить за границы, то будет во все стороны скрол. Про обновление браузеров не знаю, 2а года верстаю, всегда такое было

Comment: @KhasanAlimov если работает без этого, то в чем вопрос?

Comment: Просто меню находящаяся в шапке скрывается в правую сторону и не появляется прокрутка, а это проблема появилась когда я создавал слайдер.

Comment: @KhasanAlimov добавьте обертке слайдера, а правильнее slick-list (- если используете слик слайдер ) overflow hidden должно помочь